# Cannot push image up using padding css

Tags: html, css, image, padding

Here is a link to the image site:

[Image Site](http://jobrangers.com/newtemplate/flatone-default/image.html)

If you look, i have the image set within a gray background circle. The image itself is positioned within the circle. I set the CSS padding as:

```
padding:3px 0 0 0
```

This puts the image 3px from the top of the background gray circle border.

**I'd like to push the image up so its closer to the top of the circle**

When I set the padding as so:

```
padding:0px 0 0 0
```

It does not move the image up. **It should.**

How do I move this image up more against the top of the gray background circle.

Comment: have you tried removing the margin on the h4 element?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The image its self has about 8 transparent pixels at the top. to reduct the apparent padding you will need to crop these pixels out, either in a graphics program (eg photoshop) or on the server

Answer (score 0):

as a matter of fact just remove those inline styles and change your CSS `.fare` style like this

```
.fare{padding:0 20px}
```

please note the 20px is to provide spacing, you may not need it it at all, it goes in taste, so play around with it, I just like it more. And of course keep all the other properties in `.fare`

Answer (score 0):

I did notice that there is an h4 element above the image which will add some padding and margin automatically. I set the h4 to margin 0 and padding 0 and it helped some :-)

Answer (score 0):

Create a new div in that div and then move that div up with margin-top:-3px;